# Why are multiple fuzzy LIKE queries on the same field faster than one combined fuzzy LIKE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, sqlperformance

I was profiling some queries in SQL Server 2017 profiler, running on Amazon RDS, and came across some unexpected performance results.

These two queries return the same results, and I was expecting the first query to be faster, because it's been limited to a single LIKE. But in fact, the second query was consistently faster (Query 1 averaged 350ms and Query 2 averaged 300ms).

I am curious if anyone can explain why Query 2 is faster than Query 1?

**Query 1** [(Query Plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJZzZcYqM)

```
select * from Vehicles 
where vehicle like '%02%toyota%camry%'
```

**Query 2** [(Query Plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ8vZqt9f)

```
select * from Vehicles 
where vehicle like '%02%' and vehicle like '%toyota%' and vehicle like '%camry%'
```

The Vehicles table has 500K rows. The `vehicle` field is an indexed `varchar(300)`, and this is an example of some matching rows:

```
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 4-spd (U140E)
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 4-spd (U140E)
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 4-spd (U241E)
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 4-spd (U241E)
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 5-spd (E351)
2002 Toyota Camry LE 2.4L (2AZFE) 5-spd (E351)
```

When Statistics IO is turned on, the output is identical for both:

`Scan count 1, logical reads 4175, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0`

Comment: We might could tell you, [if you posted the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Logically, the second doesn't care the order of 02, toyota, and camry. The first one does... so i'd expect this to take longer. It just happens that you know the order of these values in your table.

Comment: @scsimon...your edit wasn't on my screen yet when I posted the same thing about order. :)

Comment: That's what I get for prematurely hitting *Add Comment*. You probably figured it out before I did anyhow @SeanLange

Comment: @scsimon - LOL. I doubt that. We shall call it a tie!!! Everyone wins a participation medal.

Comment: On top of paste the plan, you can copy/paste all the statistics IO from the executions here and see which is doing more reads/writes/scans/etc.: http://statisticsparser.com/

Comment: @scsimon SeanLange Thanks guys, new to posting about SQL performance on Stack Overflow. I just updated my question to include the query plans (links to the right of "Query X" headers)

Comment: @dfundako I compared the output from Statistics IO and it's identical for each query.

Comment: I am not at all surprised the query plans are identical. Not sure how many rows are in your table or what your table definition is but sure looks like a case where full text indexing would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me that your query could make use of an index where the wildcard is the first character. It wouldn't know whereabouts on the B Tree to start. It would have to consider each and every vehicle in your table to see if it matched.

Some possibilities:

- 300ms is very slow for an indexed read of half a dozen records. I'd expect an order of magnitude faster. You mention Amazon. Are you measuring across an internet link? If so, variations on your link speed could be interfering with your conclusions.
- Do you always run them in that order? It is possible that your second query is gaining from the fact that the first query caused the data to be cached, giving it an unfair head start.

Comment: I am using non-production class RDS instance, so the speed is likely related to that. I am executing the query over the internet, but I'm pulling the durations from profiler, so I was assuming it was giving me the duration as measured on the server, though I don't know if that's true. I ran the queries multiple times before and after each other, and the performance was consistently better in query 2.

Comment: That is interesting. What I mean by you can't use a B Tree in that way is this. Imagine I gave you a phone book and said get me the names like '%so%. You cannot use the fact that the phone book is ordered alphabetically to help you find it. You would have to scan every row and check every name against this pattern. The other thing I didn't think of is that a string like 'toyota 02 camry' would match your second test but not your first. They aren't logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two thinks that could be causing this.

1. The CPU, Memory, or other resources used to fulfill your predicate. This goes back to the fact that they are not syntax the same. One is looking for your three values in a particular order while the other is simply checking if all three predicates exist
2. Bandwidth, and other networking bottlenecks. It's easy to take this route when we are dealing with milliseconds.

Also, I would free the cache before you run these to prevent using cached plans.